# How to resolve inability to ssh into google cloud instance when the gcloud compute ssh command becomes stuck/hangs without error message?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to SSH into a Google Cloud Platform instance from an internal ip. When I run `gcloud compute ssh instance-name --internal-ip`, gcloud is able to find the zone automatically but hangs indefinitely without an error message. I have ran `gcloud --verbosity=debug compute ssh instance-name --internal-ip` to gain insight and see the program gets stuck at

```
DEBUG: Executing command: [u'/usr/bin/ssh', u'-T', u'-i', u'/home/edmond/.ssh/google_compute_engine', u'-o', u'CheckHostIP=no'...
```

Actions I have taken to try to resolve the issue:

1. Reinstall Google Cloud Platform SDK.
2. Run `gcloud compute config-ssh --remove` and then `gcloud compute config-ssh` to reset ssh keys.
3. Manually remove all google related files from `~/.ssh/` and then running `gcloud compute config-ssh`.
4. Adding my public ssh key in google cloud platform website at compute > metadata > ssh keys for the correct project.

Here are pieces of information which may be relevant:

1. I used to be able to ssh into instances without a problem and then one day this issue arised.
2. I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) version 2 on Windows 10.
3. I am connected to a VPN which makes my IP internal which is why I use `--internal-ip` flag. There are no external IPs. That's not an option.
4. I get the same issue in the Google Cloud Platform website when I use the web-based console which means the issue is not isolated to only my machine.

Comment: It's possible that sshd on the instance has failed or become misconfigured. Have you tried creating a new instance and ssh'ing into it? That would exclude your project's configuration|environment and point back to the instance.Something happened to the instance and it would be good to understand what happened that day. Did someone else affect the instance? Do you run periodic, automatic updates?

Comment: It's not one instance but many. All instances under the project.

Comment: It's possible that Google has applied a change that has broken this access but I think it's more likely that someone has made a change in your project (are you the sole owner?) that has caused this issue to arise? My next thought is that there's been a firewall rule change. Possibly some other network change.

Comment: Try to create test VM (or edit existing one) and set `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs`. After that, try to connect from this VM to other VMs in your project with command `gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE --internal-ip`.

Comment: I believe the problem is related to the VPN. The CLI `gcloud` sets up an IAP TCP tunnel for instances using private IP addresses. A VPN is not required. Shutdown your VPN and try again. If that works, then you will need to directly launch `ssh` and connect to the VM instance private IP address when the VPN tunnel is up. If you understand IP routing, take a look at the address that `gcloud` is connecting to when the VPN is down and then look at the routing table setup when the VPN is up.

Comment: @DazWilkin It would not be a Google change which is blocking my access. I know others who are able to access the machine.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza I don't have the permission to create VMs but other people are able to connect to VMs so the test you suggest is not needed.

Comment: @JohnHanley I did disconnect VPN for a sanity check but won't work since only an internal IP address will work. I connect to a VPN for that purporse. None of the VMs have an external IP address. When I turned off the VPN I got error code 255. I believe the solution for that would be to open up port 22 on an external IP of the instances which is not permissible. The most annoying part is I'm unable to connect to VM instances through the Cloud Shell on the Google Cloud console. There is probably some issue associated with my account since I'm unable to SSH from my machine or the Cloud Shell.

Comment: I suggested this test to check if you have problems on your VPN (in case if test succeeded) or  your issue related to SSH (if test failed). As I wrote, you can use existed VM to do this test - all you need to set `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs` and try to connect from this VM to other VMs in your project with `command gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE --internal-ip`. And as I know, it's the easiest way to check SSH if you decided not to use external IP.

Comment: The CLI gcloud can connect to VM instances that do not have a public IP address. Your assumption that this will not work is incorrect. If this is failing with the VPN shutdown, you have a different problem.

Comment: @JohnHanley That's not right. Gcloud can connect to VM instances which do not have public IP address.The docs clearly state to use the `--internal-ip` flag when you want to "Connect to instances using their internal IP addresses rather than their external IP addresses. Use this to connect from one instance to another on the same VPC network, over a VPN connection, or between two peered VPC networks." Therefore, gcloud can connect to VM instances which don't have an external IP by using their internal IP.

Comment: @JohnHanley Good news I have narrowed down the problem by fiddling more with the VPN. In general, I can't shh into instances when I'm connected to the VPN. When I work remotely the assumption is connecting to the VPN will allow me to use `--internal-ip` flag. Since no external IPs, VPN is my only option at home. At work however, I'm already on an internal network. I still connect to the VPN by habit for other services. When I disconnected from VPN, while at work, I was able to SSH. In conclusion, the VPN IP is not considered internal is what I'm led to believe.

Comment: @EdmondWeiss - Reread my comments. I said that gcloud can connect to a private IP address. The CLI uses TCP port forwarding via IAP. I know the low level details and internals of this process.

Comment: Since you have problem with SSH connectivity only through your VPN it'll be useful to have more information about your VPN in the question.